# Moodle standard_end_of_body function location?

Tags: php, moodle

I'm trying to customize the rendering of the `standard_end_of_body()`, but I can't seem to find the proper function.

I found the abstract function in `/lib/outputrenderers.php`, but not the actual theme implementation. In the code it is mentioned that it should be in the theme renderer, so I checked into every renderer, as well as the themes mine is based in (bootstrap and Elegance), but so far, nada.

So I'm very much open to any suggestions!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `/theme/yourtheme/renderers/php`

add this

```
class theme_yourtheme_core_renderer extends core_renderer {
    public function standard_end_of_body_html() {
        // Optionally add the parent html.
        $output = parent::standard_end_of_body_html();

        $output .= 'my stuff';

        return ($output);
    }
```

alternatively, you can also add footer html to the setting `additionalhtmlfooter`

via site admin -> appearance -> additional html

or direct to /admin/settings.php?section=additionalhtml